# MySQL Unique Index error?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE tblUser 
( 

    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i_ITUsername ON tblUser (ITUsername),
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i_email ON tblUser (email),
    CREATE INDEX i_disability ON tblUser (disability),
    CREATE INDEX i_name ON tblUser (name)
) TYPE = MyISAM;
```

Can anyone see why I am getting an error at the first unique index line? As far as I am aware, there is no error :(

Comment: Could you add the error message that you receive on performing the action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error is you have two data type on one column,

```
mobilePhone long int UNSIGNED not null, -- choose one INT or LONG
housePhone long int UNSIGNED,
```

The second is you are declaring like `TSQL`, here's for mysql,

```
primary key (ITUsername),
UNIQUE i_ITUsername  (ITUsername),
UNIQUE i_email (email),
KEY i_disability  (disability),
KEY i_name (name)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9303)